# About copy control in C++

Tags: c++, constructor

I defined a class named Student.

```
// Student.h
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Student {
public:
    Student();
    Student(const Student &s);
    Student(int ii);
    Student& operator=(const Student &s);
    ~Student();
private:
    int i;
};

// Student.cpp
#include "Student.h"

Student::Student(): i(0)
{
    cout << "ctor" << endl;
}

Student::Student(const Student &s)
{
    i = s.i;
    cout << "copy constructor" << endl;
}

Student::Student(int ii): i(ii)
{
    cout << "Student(int ii)" <<  endl;
}

Student& Student::operator=(const Student &s)
{
    cout << "assignment operator" << endl;
    i = s.i;
    return *this;
}

Student::~Student()
{
}

// main.cpp
#include <vector>
#include "Student.h"

int main()
{
    vector<Student> s(5);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I ran this program on Visual Studio 2015.
Output result:

```
ctor  
ctor  
ctor  
ctor  
ctor
```

But I expect the result is:

```
ctor  
copy constructor  
copy constructor  
copy constructor  
copy constructor  
copy constructor
```

Am I wrong?  Additionally, I wrote:

```
Student s1;
Student s2 = s1;
```

Output result:

```
ctor  
copy constructor
```

instead of:

```
ctor  
copy constructor  
copy constructor
```

as C++ primer(the fourth edition) said in Chapter 13.

The third one, when I wrote:

```
Student s = 3;
```

Output result:

```
Student(int ii)
```

I think this one should be:

```
Student(int ii)  
copy constructor
```

Comment: Not really sure why you expect an extra copy construction in the second example.

Comment: In Ch. 13, we saw that copy initialization first uses the indicated constructor to create a temporary object. It then uses that copy constructor to copy that temporary into the one we are creating.

Comment: I'd expect that if it involved a type conversion. But it doesn't.

Comment: Why does C++ primer(4ed) put it in that way？

Answer (score 7):

If you consult the documentation on [`std::vector::vector(size_type count)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) You would see that

> Constructs the container with count default-inserted instances of T. No copies are made.

So you only will see constructor calls.

Secondly in

```
Student s1;
Student s2 = s1;
```

`s2 = s1` is not using the assignment operator but instead it is using [copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization).  This uses the copy constructor to construct the string.

In your third example

```
Student(int ii)  
copy constructor
```

Would be a valid output.  The reason you do not get that is that the compiler is smart and instead of creating a temporary `Student` and then making a copy it can elide out the copy and directly construct `s` using the constructor that takes an `int`.

Comment: I know the difference between copy and direct initialization. But I am confused about the description in this book.

Comment: @NiklausTseng I would have to see the section of the book that says `Student s2 = s1;` should give `ctor  
copy constructor  
copy constructor`

Comment: In Ch. 13, authors say that copy initialization first uses the indicated constructor to create a temporary object. It then uses that copy constructor to copy that temporary into the one we are creating.

Comment: @NiklausTseng That just sounds wrong.  There is no reason to make a copy and then copy from the copy.  You can just copy from the source.  Do not that books are not always 100% correct.